# TypeScript Get the correct `keyof ` of an inner map

Tags: typescript

Here's my code

```
const functions={
    top1: {
        f1: () => 'string',
        f2: (b: boolean, n: number) => 1
    },
    top2: {
        f3: (b: boolean) => b
    }
}
```

And I want to create an `apply` function which looks like this:

```
function apply (top: keyof typeof functions, functionName: string, inputs: any[]) {
    return functions[top][functionName](...inputs)
}
```

So that I can console.log the following values

```
console.log(apply('top1', 'f1', [])); // 'string'
console.log(apply('top1', 'f2', [true, 23])); // 1
console.log(apply('top2', 'f3', [false])); // false
apply('top2', 'f3', [1]); // show throw TS error
```

However, I have the following error, with `--strict` mode:

"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '...' has no index signature"

Which is understandable since `functionName` is a string, and not a `keyof typeof functions[section]`. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use generic type parameters to capture the concrete keys that are passed to the function. If you do this, typescript will allow you to index.

You also want to use some conditional types to extract the parameter types and the return type in order to have type safety with regard to the passed in arguments and the return value type

```
const functions={
    top1: {
        f1: () => 'string',
        f2: (b: boolean, n: number) => 1
    },
    top2: {
        f3: (b: boolean) => b
    }
}

type WeakParameters<T> = T extends (...a: infer A) => any ? A : never;
type WeakReturnType<T> = T extends (...a: any) => infer R ? R : never; 
function apply<KOutter extends keyof (typeof functions),
    KInner extends keyof (typeof functions[KOutter])>(
        top: KOutter, functionName: KInner, inputs: WeakParameters<(typeof functions)[KOutter][KInner]>) : WeakReturnType<(typeof functions)[KOutter][KInner]>{
    var fn = functions[top][functionName]; // OK
    return (fn as unknown as (...a:any[])=> any)(...inputs)
}
console.log(apply('top1', 'f1', [])); // 'string'
console.log(apply('top1', 'f2', [true, 23])); // 1
console.log(apply('top2', 'f3', [false])); // false
apply('top2', 'f3', [1]); // show throw TS error
```

**Note** We will still need to use a type assertion unfortunately. Although the compiler lets us index into `functions` with `top` and `functionName` it will not be able to figure out that `fn` is a function so we can't call it directly (hence the type assertion `as unknown as (...a:any[])=> any`). Also because of this (because TS can't figure out `(typeof functions)[KOutter][KInner]` is a function), we can't use the built-in conditional type `Parameters` and `ReturnType` to extact the parameter types and the return type, and we need to write our own versions of these that do not require the type parameter to be provably a function (although things will work as expected when calling the function)